# How do I turn performance monitoring off in Azure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I visited [the this web page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/3679de4b-6e66-43f2-9058-91607e8e7530/40544the-database-tempdb-has-reached-its-size-quota-partition-or-delete-data-drop-indexes-or?forum=ssdsgetstarted). I get the same error message but the server version is 12. According to one of the posts it is possible to solve a problem by turning performance monitoring off. I did log on to the Azure Portal but I cannot find this option anywhere. How do I turn it off? I guess that performance monitoring actually has another name in this context.

I guess that there are many people out there who would like to know how to turn it off. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I found "performance monitoring" for web apps earlier today but not for databases.

Comment: instead of sticking to some random advice which may or may not be true..Can you try find out which queries are using tempdb more ,by following this link:http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/how-to-identify-which-query-is-filling-up-the-tempdb-transaction-log

Comment: Thank you! It is possible that a trigger is one of the reasons I'm experiencing trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The V12 server model does not have a way to disable performance monitoring, as such.  It is also different in how tempdb works, meaning that you should not assume that tempdb being full strictly implies that performance monitoring was the cause.

The size of tempdb in v12 is substantially larger than V11.  it is also not shared across customers (unlike in v11), so generally having out-of-space issues on tempdb in v12 is a result of large queries or other operations that consume significant space there.  If your workload is hitting cases like this and you do not have an obvious way to make it work, please open up a support case with Microsoft and we will assist you.